# How do I use foreach for complex nest loop with multiple actions within loop?

Tags: r, foreach, nested-loops, doparallel

I have this code - see below. I would like to convert it using the R foreach functionality so I use parallel processing.

However, I am not seeing an obvious way because there are multiple actions within each loop.

Any thoughts?

```
   for (x in 1:test) {for (y in 1:TotalP) {
   payout[(svx[x,y]+1):Prow,y]<-0
   ifelse(svx[x,y]<=LapseSum[[y]],payout[(ts+svx[x,y]),y]<-(face_value[y]+payout[(ts+svx[x,y]),y]),0)
   lifetracker[(svx[x,y]+1):Prow,y]<-0}
   Cash_Flow<-cbind(Cash_Flow, apply(payout,1,sum))
   lifesum<-cbind(lifesum, apply(lifetracker,1,sum))
   coitracker<-cbind(coitracker, apply(payout,1,sumneg))
   payout<-coi
   payout<-payout+Purchase
   lifetracker<-lifetracker2}
```

Comment: Just dropping a foreach in the first loop results in: "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: Maybe breaking it into separate loops might work - but I am not sure where to start. This loop creates a random outcome from a life insurance portfolio, sums cash flows by month, then creates another scenario.

Comment: Take a look at %:%, the foreach loop nesting operator and see if it helps with your problem (skimming it looks plausible that it will work).

Comment: The loop seems to be updating some variables that exist outside it. In order to parallelize you need the parallel runs to be independent. That is, you need to reframe your inner loop as a function that gives a separate output for each value of x and then use that output to update your global variables.

Comment: This recent R-bloggers post on parallelization and nested operations might be on interest: https://www.r-bloggers.com/can-you-nest-parallel-operations-in-r/